# Flapdoodle embedded mongodb tests fail on Jenkins but pass locally

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am trying to run some tests with flapdoodle embedded mongodb that pass locally, but when I start the build on Jenkins it fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
                    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
                            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
                                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
                                    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
                                        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException
                                            Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException
                                                Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException`
```

I am using gradle, my guess would be the versions, but I can't reproduce the error locally:
`testCompile("de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo:2.0.0")`
`org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Dalston.SR2` and `springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'`

Does anyone know why this is happening? Any advice on what can I do so the build on Jenkins passes?

Comment: Do you have an instance of `mongod` running locally when you run the tests?

Comment: Yes, I have it on a docker container. Does it have something to do with that? even though i am using the embedded mongo for the tests?

Comment: I was unable to run tests with flapdoodle if I had a `mongod` instance running. Could you kill the `mongod` process and try again?

Comment: it works without mongo started, but only locally

Comment: Problem solved then. You can close this

Comment: yes but only locally, and it worked with mongo started also. Maybe i should have rephrased my previous comment, sorry. On Jenkins it still fails

Comment: Is this fixed. Because I got the same problem running it on a gitlab runner. But locally it works. Maybe because I use localhost?